Soap Node - Request Entity Too Large
I am executing a request with Node with many characters with a result of "413-Request Entity Too Large", but executing from the Soap UI IDE the result is OK.
Tried using without success :
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' })) // without success

The Node lets it pass but apparently it does not execute the request in soap-node.
Could you help me?
Request Json:
file: 'H4EgCq8iBMIP'... 294732 more characters'

Response Error:
 response: {
    status: 413,
    statusText: 'Request Entity Too Large',
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      server: 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0',
      'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET',
      'server-timing': 'dtSInfo;desc="0", dtRpid;desc="-1340319640"',
      'set-cookie': [Array],
      date: 'Mon, 17 Jun 2024 00:52:08 GMT',
      connection: 'close',
      'content-length': '0'
    },
_header: 'POST /xxxxxService/xxxxxxService.svc HTTP/1.1' +
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,text/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' +
        'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: node-soap/1.0.3\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: none\r\n' +
        'Accept-Charset: utf-8\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        'Host: xxxxxx.com\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 294732\r\n' +
        'SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IService1/xxxxxx"\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
   data: ''
  },
  body: ''


